# Inner Array in IPHONE

Tags: iphone, ios5

I am new in iphone , I have try lot but did not found any solutions.

I want output like this

```
 [
        {
           "longitude" : -71.449162,
           "latitude" : 42.734752
        },
        {
           "longitude" : -71.447343,
           "latitude" : 42.735636
        },
        {
           "longitude" : -71.446246,
           "latitude" : 42.735807
        }
     ]
```

But I get output like this

```
"longitude":"(
   "42.713974",
   "-71.449432",
   "42.713757",
   "-71.449471",
   "42.713474",
   "-71.449516",

)", "latitude":"(
   "42.713974",
   "-71.449432",
   "42.713757",
   "-71.449471",
   "42.713474",
   "-71.449516",

)
```

**I want longitude and latitude value in separate array.**

Thanks

Comment: Please post the code that is generating, storing, and printing this data.

Comment: @Nirav Ranpara My answer is useful or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
NSMutableArray *mytest = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"-71.449162",@"-71.447343",@"-71.446246",nil];

NSMutableArray *mytest1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"42.734752",@"42.735636",@"42.735807",nil];

NSMutableArray *testArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i = 0; i< 3; i++) {
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setObject:[mytest objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"longitude"];
[dict setObject:[mytest1 objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"latitude"];
[testArray addObject:dict];


 }

NSLog(@"my array is : %@",testArray);

NSError *error;

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:testArray options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error]; 

NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 

NSLog(@"json string is : \n%@",jsonString);
```

Comment: But I want "["  this not "("

Comment: @NiravRanpara try this code...  NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:testArray options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"json string is : \n%@",jsonString);

Comment: @NiravRanpara, the above comment is helpful or not?

Answer (score 0):

Store latitude and longitude as string format in seperate array and try using this code

```
NSMutableArray * totalArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
NSArray* temp=[[NSArray alloc]initwithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Latitude%@",[latitudearray objectAtIndex:i]],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Longitudee%@",[longitudearray objectAtIndex:i]],nil];
[totalArray addObject:temp];
 }

  NSLog(@"%@",totalArray);
```

Hope this Helps...

Comment: But I want "[" this not "("